# ¿Cual es el opuesto al comando frozenset() en Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Si he "congelado" un conjunto en Python 3 con frozenset(), como lo "descongelo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python hay dos tipos/clases estándar para representar conjuntos, `set` (mutable) y `frozenset` (inmutable).  La implementación de ambos es la misma excepto porque el primero tiene métodos que permiten modificarlo (`update`, `add`, etc).

La razón de la existencia de dos tipos diferentes es simplemente por cuestiones de funcionalidad, al ser `frozenset` inmutable es "hashable" y por tanto puede servir como clave en un diccionario por ejemplo.

`frozenset` no es una "función" que actúe sobre un conjunto y lo haga temporalmente inmutable, sino que es una clase cuyo constructor acepta un iterable cualquiera (incluido por tanto otro conjunto) y construye un nuevo conjunto inmutable a partir del mismo (objeto/instancia `frozenset`).

Con esto quiero decir, que un objeto `frozenset` no se puede hacer mutable ni un `set` hacer inmutable en si mismos, in-place. Si deseas modificar el conjunto lo único que debes hacer es construir otro conjunto (otro objeto) a partir de él pero usando `set`:

> ```
> >>> inmut_set = frozenset((1, 2, 2, 4, 5))
> >>> mut_set = set(inmut_set)
> ```

obviamente puedes reasignar a la misma variable el nuevo objeto, pero siempre ten en cuanta que son objetos distintos:

> ```
> >>> conj = frozenset((1, 2, 2, 4, 5))
> >>> conj = set(conj)
> ```

pero ten siempre en cuenta que son dos objetos distintos, esto es importante si por ejemplo tienes varias variables asociadas al conjunto inicial.